# Why is my inner function returning as undefined in my simple Javascript OOP game

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm building a pretty simple! game using Object Oriented Programming in Javascript. The score function,
while being called from within another function, is returning as 'undefined';

i set a var for 'this' and named it 'that'. then used 'that' from within the inner function

```
bobsGame = {}

bobsGame.player  = function(which){
this.which = which;
this.which.score = 0;
that = this;

this.setScore = function(which, diceVal){
    score = that.which.score;
    console.log(score);
    $('#'+which+'-score').html(score);
    }

this.rollDice = function() {
    diceVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    $('#'+which+'-dice-val').html(diceVal);
    /* console.log(which, diceVal); These vars are correct */
    that.setScore(which, diceVal); //returns undefined
    }
}

var player1 = new bobsGame.player('player1');
var player2 = new bobsGame.player('player2'); 

$('#roll-dice-btn-1').click(function(){
player1.rollDice();
});
$('#roll-dice-btn-2').click(function(){
player2.rollDice();
});
```

Comment: You will have problems because you defined the variables globally, not locally. `that.setScore(which, diceVal); //returns undefined`, `setScore` doesn't return any value, so the return value will be `undefined`.

Comment: Oh, it looks like you are confused why `that.which.score` is undefined? Because `that.which` is a **string** primitive and any properties you set on primitive values exist only temporary. Example: `var foo = "foo"; foo.bar = 0; console.log(foo.bar);`. So maybe you just use `this.score`/`that.score` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got some fundamental problems with your game that you're just not really grasping.

The idea of setting a value `which` (which is basically your players name) is fine, but then you're trying to keep the score of that player on their name. If you ignore the fundamental issue of that not being possible since the name (`which`) is a string, as the other answers point out, and examine what you're trying to do; it looks like you're trying to keep track of each players' score in an object that you can access at any time to get the complete game state. Unfortunately, the way you have this built - that just won't work. You're creating a new player object for each player - and those players are stored separately in memory and can not access each other.

The structure you've tried to build here isn't going to work for what it LOOKS like you're trying to do, and that's before you even get to the actual syntactical & logical implementation problems that you're struggling with right now.

What you really want is probably something a little more like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var BobsGame = function()
{
    this.Players = [];
    this.current_player_turn = 0;
}

BobsGame.prototype.addPlayer = function(Player)
{
    Player.Game = this;
    this.Players.push(Player);
    Player.setId(this.Players.length);

    return this;
}

BobsGame.prototype.updateWinner = function()
{
    var Winner = null;
    for (var i = 0, players = this.Players.length; i < players; i++)
    {
        if (!Winner || (this.getPlayer(i) && this.getPlayer(i).score > Winner.score))
        {
            Winner = this.getPlayer(i);
        }
    }

    $('#game-winner').text(Winner.name + " won with a score of " + Winner.score + "!");
}


BobsGame.prototype.getPlayer = function(id)
{
    return this.Players[ id ] || null;
}

var Player = function(name)
{
    this.Game = null;

    this.score = 0;
    this.name = 0;
    this.id = 0;
}

Player.prototype.roll = function()
{
    diceVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    return this.setScore(diceVal);
}

Player.prototype.setScore(new_score)
{
    this.score = new_score;
    $('#' + this.name + '-dice-val').text(new_score);
    this.score = diceVal;

    return this;
}

///implementation

var myGame = new BobsGame();
var Player1 = new Player("Player 1");
var Player2 = new Player("Player 2");

myGame.addPlayer(Player1).addPlayer(Player2);

$('#roll-dice-btn-1').click(function(){
    Player1.roll();
    myGame.updateWinner();
});

$('#roll-dice-btn-2').click(function(){
    Player2.roll();
    myGame.updateWinner();
});
</script>
```

The above code creates a game object, which stores the state for the entire game. It also defines and creates a couple of Player objects, which are both responsible for storing their own state (id, name, and score). A player knows how to roll the dice (the roll method), and then you use the Game object to determine which player won.

This application structure is much easier to reason about, and separates the concerns of what the game is responsible for, and what players are responsible for.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your issue boils down to strings as string-literals, versus strings as String object instances.

```
var player = new Player("bob");
```

where

```
Player = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.name.score = 0; // here is the root of the problem
}
```

The crux is that string-literals can't have properties added to them, dynamically, due to how JS treats them.

```
Player = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = 0;
}
```

should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies here:

```
bobsGame.player  = function(which){
  this.which = which;
  this.which.score = 0;
  /* ... */
};

var player1 = new bobsGame.player('player1');
```

`which` is a primitive string and you are trying do define a property in it.

Transform `which` in a object or in a object String and you will be fine.

```
this.which = new String(which);
this.which.score = 0;
```

or (what I personally prefer)

```
// Dont forget to update the rest of your code.
this.player = {
   name: which,
   score: 0
};
```